# Frigidaire freezer stuck in sabbath mode

Tags: kitchens, refrigerator, freezer

Frigidaire Freezer Sabbath Mode

I’ve got this Frigidaire professional fridge/freezer side by side and the freezer is showing this error code.

I looked up online and apparently this means the control panel is in Sabbath mode. I have no idea how it got like this.

So I looked up online and I haven’t been able to figure out how to reset this from the control panel. The control panel is pretty much frozen  what I mean by that is that none of the buttons work. The minus sign and the temp buttons don’t work and none of the other hidden buttons are showing up. I’ve tried holding both at the same time for 10-15 seconds and nothing.

I also found out that if I disconnect the power for thirty minutes it’ll reset. So I did that by disconnecting the cord to the control panel. I did not unplug it or flip a breaker for thirty minutes. After reconnecting the internal wires the control panel said Er and then Ce. I figure that means error code - communication error. After a while though it goes back to sabbath mode.

I’m stumped. My next step is flipping the breaker to the freezer for thirty minutes. Anyone have any other ideas?[image]

Comment: Just flip the breaker. Food will stay perfectly cool if you leave it closed.

Comment: Voting to close because there is no element of DIY or Home Improvement to this question.  You follow the information in the product manual and/or the manufacturer's youtube tutorials *that are specific to this function*, and if that doesn't work you phone the manufacturer's customer service number.

Comment: What is the model #?

Answer (score 2):

From a quick search with Star-K and other sources, Sabbath mode on the Frigidaire models is generally + and - or up/down at the same time for 5 seconds. Or possible CONTROL LOCK + TEMP MODE (MODE F C). It varies by model, so we need the model # to give a definitive answer.

If that doesn't work, then go ahead with cutting all power (breaker or unplug from the wall) for 30 minutes - that will not harm your food at all as a modern refrigerator should keep food at a safe temperature for at least 4 hours with power out as long as you keep the door closed.

> *by disconnecting the cord to the control panel*

That is the equivalent of unplugging the keyboard, mouse and monitor from a desktop computer. Which will have virtually no effect (maybe Windows will make a few disconnect/reconnect noises) and certainly not the same as pulling the plug. So it is totally expected that disconnecting the control panel will not change the Sabbath mode status.

I suspect that Sabbath mode does not reset from a short power outage because for those who make use of it (I don't have a refrigerator with Sabbath mode, but I do have a Kitchenaid oven with Sabbath mode), it needs to run unattended for 25 - 73 hours at a time. A short power outage, as can easily happen with a passing thunderstorm (lights blink, clocks reset, but power comes right back on) during that time would cause serious problems if it turned off Sabbath mode.

Also note that a refrigerator/freezer in Sabbath mode is still fully functional, except possibly for ice/water functions and lighting. It may run somewhat less efficiently, depending on how it controls the compressor and fan, but it will still keep food at a safe temperature.

Comment: Given that non-volatile memory is cheap and common, powering down normally wouldn't erase them. You don't want things like WiFi connection, date-time, freezer settings, etc. all erase just because of a power outage.

Comment: @Nelson Agreed. The difference is that Sabbath mode by itself is more like turning a switch on or off - you could easily expect it to reset to the default (which is non-Sabbath mode) on a power outage. Deliberately having it not do so and yet (perhaps driven by a battery-backed clock) automatically go back to non-Sabbath mode after an extended outage is quite logical in my mind but different from a simple "write the setting to non-volatile memory each time it is changed and restore to that setting on power-up".

Comment: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/858174/Frigidaire-Freezer.html?page=10

Looks like it doesn't reset on some models "The unit stays in Sabbath mode after a power failure recovery. It must be deactivated with the buttons on the control panel."